# Elements rendered with Jquery Templates all affected by same event handler

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-templates

I am using JQuery Templates to render a number of tables from a JSON data source.

Once the tables are rendered, I am attaching a Jquery "hover" event handler (via table CSS class) to highlight table columns.

The hover event works, but affects all rendered tables of the same CSS class - so If I hover over column 2 of table 1, column 2 of ALL my tables are also highlighted.

I would much prefer not to attach an individual ID for each table - nothing else would need it.

I have done some Googling and the use of JQuery "closest()" in the hover event handler seems promising, but I cannot figure out the correct usage :(

Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    drawRows();
    setColumnHover();
});

function drawRows() {
    var jsonData = jQuery.parseJSON(getJsonString());
    $("#tableTemplate").tmpl(jsonData).appendTo("#funnelBody");
    }

function setColumnHover() {
   /* Ref: http://www.local-guru.net/blog/2010/10/29/table-column-highlighting-with-jquery */
    $(".statsTable td").hover(
        function() {
            var idx = $(this).parent().children('td,th').index($(this)) + 1;
            if (idx > 1) {
                $('td:nth-child(' + idx + ')').addClass('hover');
                $('th:nth-child(' + idx + ')').addClass('hover');
            }
        }
        ,
        function() {
            var idx = $(this).parent().children('td,th').index($(this)) + 1;
            if (idx > 1) {
                $('td:nth-child(' + idx + ')').removeClass('hover');
                $('th:nth-child(' + idx + ')').removeClass('hover');
            }
        }
    );
}

///////////// Rendered HTML
<table class="statsTable">
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Did the below solution not work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to focus on assigning the class by "this" instead of by name.  The following should do the trick.

```
$(".statsTable td").hover(
    function() {     
        $(this).addClass('hover');
    },
    function() {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    }
);
```

Comment: This looked good and seemed to be very close - but now the event handler is highlighting each hovered _row_ rather than the hovered column :(

Comment: oh then erase the parent and child methods.

Comment: that should work, thought u wanted the rows highlighted.    if you also want the headers hightlighted make the initial selector $(".statsTable td, .statsTable th")

Answer (score 0):

Give some other class along with statsTable something like this.

```
///////////// Rendered HTML
<table class="statsTable hoverClass">
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and then use this class as a selector

```
$(".hoverClass td")
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but would this not just put be back into the same situation, since all tables would have <table class="statsTable hoverClass" ?